# performance issues because too many instances

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

our client reported a performance problem with DefaultStockService. After checking the client’s system running SELECT COUNT(*)FROM {StockLevelHistoryEntry), we discovered that there are hundreds of millions of instances of StockLevelHistoryEntry.
What is the best way to resolve this performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested in the stock level history (they are only used for auditing purposes, they serve no other value for the commerce system), you can control it on your `StockLevel` objects in backoffice. There is a field called `maxStockLevelHistoryCount` that indicates if you want to store history records.

[image]

Despite the name, this number is **NOT** the max amount of entries. If it's set to `0`, no history entries will be saved. If it has `any other value` (positive or negative), a history entry will be created. You can validate this within the `DefaultStockService` code.

If you want to store only a limited amount of entries (for example only changes from the last 3 years for auditing purposes), you will have to create something custom yourself. Either customize the `DefaultStockService` or create a cronjob that periodically removes history entries.

For your existing entries, you will have to create something yourself to remove them. This can be done through a script or an impex